# In Gmail, what causes email content to yield to white space at right?

Tags: gmail, google-chrome

The huge white space on the right appears more often than not in Gmail for Google Apps. This does not leave much horizontal width for email contents. Is there a way to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: FYI: the same applies to Outlook.com albeit the column on the right is thinner. In the case of Outlook, you can get rid of that column by upgrading to a paid account. Perhaps there is something similar with Google?

Comment: That would be acceptable. However, this is already a paid account.

Comment: Do you see ads on there ?

Comment: No, there are never ads. I do not run any ad blocking, either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space is reserved for ads and for the [people widget](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1251806) (if enabled). The only way to “prevent it” or to remove it is by using some Greasemonkey/Userscript or browser extension. (See [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ad-blocker-for-gmail/coibnogmjcpbccgjofoiklnfpbbjbapo) if you are using Chrome.)